# spring beans Context Configuration

Tags: spring, frameworks

I am a newbie to spring beans. I'm referring books and blogs. In some the context configuration is given as `<beans:bean>` and in some just `<beans>`. What is the difference? Should we give the XML namespace in the context file? Will it refer the acutal site at the time of application deployment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter as far as Spring is concerned - the XML must be valid so that Spring can understand it, that's it. It is up to you which format you choose. Normally you use default namespace to avoid typing too much (all examples based on [Appendix C. XML Schema-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="..."/>

</beans>
```

`xmlns="..."` attribute defines default namespace (the one used if you don't specify any namespace at all, like `<beans/>`. This is fine as long as you use only single `beans` namespace and occasionally few declarations from other namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="..." class="...">
      <property name="isolation">
        <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE"/>
      </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

But sometimes you'll notice you are using way more nodes from different namespaces compared to default `beans` namespace. A good example is [Spring Security configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) file:

```
<beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config='true'>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:openid-login>
            <security:attribute-exchange>
                <security:openid-attribute name="email" type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" />
                <security:openid-attribute name="name" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson" />
            </security:attribute-exchange>
        </security:openid-login>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

You see how clumsy it is because `beans` default namespace is used so rarely but the whole file must be cluttered with `security:` prefix? What about this (notice how `xmlns` namespace declarations have changed):

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </session-management>
        <openid-login>
            <attribute-exchange>
                <openid-attribute name="email" type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" />
                <openid-attribute name="name" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson" />
            </attribute-exchange>
        </openid-login>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

These two configuration files are semantically equivalent (it is just a different way to encode the same information). But the latter is much more readable. Just use default namespace whichever namespace is used the most.

Comment: Ha, almost same time and same response ;) +1 for more complete (and working I suppose) Spring Security example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on XML namespace configuration and is not Spring feature, makes no difference for the code, make some difference to coder, and in fact but effect of defining `xmlns` attribute on root xml element. [Read more about `<beans:bean>` in this chapter of Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e507) (which isn't in fact the same as Spring Framework, but is very common and uses its own namespace in XML files). You can write:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
  </global-method-security>

  <beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class=
        "org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="myPermissionEvaluator"/>
  </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

which is equivalent to:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" <!-- see the difference here? -->
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
  <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
  </security:global-method-security>

  <bean id="expressionHandler" class=
        "org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="myPermissionEvaluator"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Personally I always use beans as main namespace, but it's matter of habit.